# Given a room number, find the floor on which room it lies java

Tags: java, algorithm

I came across a question where I had to find the floor by using given room no, according to the following distribution:

```
floor    rooms
1        1-5
2        6-15
3        16-20
4        21-30
5        31-35
6        36-45
```

. Suppose if I am giving room number as "37" program should say "floor number is 6". Though I have given below solution for it but I itself felt its not a good solution. I believe It may fail if the number of floor is increasing.

```
    int queryRoom = 37;
    int totalFloor = 6;

    int currentRm = 0;
    int floorInQuestion = 1; // staring floor

    while (floorInQuestion != totalFloor) {
        if (floorInQuestion % 2 != 0) {
            currentRm = currentRm + 5;
        } else {
            currentRm = currentRm + 10;
        }
        if (queryRoom <= currentRm)
            break;
        floorInQuestion++;
    }

    System.out.println(floorInQuestion);
```

Comment: And what is the **specific** question you have?

Comment: [codereview.se] might be a better place for this question.

Comment: You seem to have deduced a mathematical rule for the floor-room distribution. I have never seen any hotel where the rooms were distributed according to such a mathematical rule. It's probably just that the first floor has technical rooms that don't exist in the second floor, that the third floor has rooms larger than the second one, etc. I would NOT try to deduce a mathematical rule, and instead simply have a list of floors, each having a range (or set) of room numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Math formula:

```
int queryRoom = 37;
queryRoom--; // create 0-based index

int a = queryRoom / 15;
int b = queryRoom % 15;

int floorInQuestion = (a * 2);
if(b < 5) floorInQuestion++;
else floorInQuestion += 2;
```

Comment: There is no need to deduce a mathematical formulae just for the sake of it, based on inputs in such a case. As soon as distribution is uneven this solution will go for a toss.

Comment: I create Math formula based on his code, what do you mean by "distribution is uneven this solution will go for a toss." ?

Comment: Right now each floor has a particular number of rooms what about the case when there is no clear pattern. Ideally it should have just been a solution bases on range checks.

Comment: He's asking how to improve his code speed. He already figure out the solution by using iteration, I just show to him the math. In the case when there is no clear pattern, then it's another case.

Comment: In that case,  I will agree with your solution. But the approach taken by OP needs to be relooked.

Comment: Since the distribution is a given, this solution is fine.